# Let $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ be bounded and for all $c\in(a,b),~f$ is Riemann integrable on $[c,b].$ Prove that $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b].$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, proof-verification

*Please tell me whether my proof for the following problem will work:*

> Let $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ be bounded and for all $c\in(a,b),~f$ is Riemann integrable on $[c,b].$ Prove that $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b].$

Since $f$ is bounded on $[a,b]$ $\exists~B>0$ (sufficiently large) such that $|f(x)|<B$ on $[a,b]$ and $B>\dfrac{\epsilon}{4(b-a)}\cdots(1)$

Choose $\epsilon>0.$ Then for $c=a+\dfrac{\epsilon}{4B}$ we have $c\in(a,b)$ [due to $1$].

$\exists$ a partition $P$ of $[c,b]$ such that $U(P,f)-L(P,f)<\epsilon/2.$

Consider the partition $P'$ of $[a,b]$ where $P'=P\cup\{a\}$

Then $$U(P',f)-L(P',f)=(\sup_{[a,c]}f(x)-\inf_{[a,c]}f(x))(c-a)+U(P,f)-L(P,f)\\<2B\times\dfrac{\epsilon}{4B}+\epsilon/2=\epsilon$$

Hence $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b].$

Comment: Your proof doesn't "read well", for example, in $(1)$ you have an $\epsilon$ but you dont choose the $\epsilon$ until the next line.

Comment: It is true that you should pick your $\epsilon$ before using it to help find the right size $B$ in your proof. However, your instincts and follow through are good! You took an arbitrary $\epsilon > 0$ and using the situation, you showed that there is a partition $P'$ of $[a,b]$ with $U(P',f)-L(P',f) < \epsilon$.